# How to use vim's errorformat %* to match a regex .* equivalent?

Tags: vim, errorformat

I'd like to use vim's errorformat to match the output of my makeprg. However it looks like the match should be a complete match, therefore I need to use `.*` regex like matchers. So far I've found `%*[^ ]` the closest, but I need to match spaces as well.

To be more particular:
I want to match an output like this:

```
|| Assertion failed: (it != c.end()), function Foo, file /Users/Me/Path/to/MyPath, line 30.
```

So far I tried with this (not working):

```
:set errorformat+=,%*[]file\ %f\\,\ line\ %l
```

Comment: Please, add some sample output.

Comment: Updated to give an example output.

Comment: Also tried with this:
set errorformat+=,%.%#file\ %f\\,\ line\ %l
Vim's documentations says:
"%.%#"  (".*")   matches a (possibly empty) string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would try:

```
set errorformat=\|\|%m\\,\ file\ %f\\,\ line\ %l.
```

Please look at `:h errorformat` for more information.

To make it easier to debug these kind of things it is nice to save the error output into a file and use `:cgetfile` if using `:make` is too time consuming.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was not working like this, and I found out this is because the dot character at the end must be matched too.
So this would be the correct one: `set errorformat+=%m\\,\ file\ %f\\,\ line\ %l%.
`